# C# Xamarin Create chart with Microcharts

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, charts

I am trying to create a chart with Microcharts. The problem is that I get the points from a List called PriceList. First take a look at this website: https://blog.xamarin.com/microcharts-elegant-cross-platform-charts-for-any-app/

So, I have to make something like this:

```
foreach (var p in PriceList)
{
     List<Microcharts.Entry> entries = new List<Microcharts.Entry>
     {
         new Entry(212)
         {
             Label = "UWP",
             ValueLabel = "212",
             Color = SKColor.Parse("#2c3e50")
         }
     } 
}
```

First of all, it gives an error on the word Entry. "The type or namespace 'Entry' does not exist in the namespace 'Microcharts' (Are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Second, I need the correct values from the List in the points. This is the List class:

```
public class price
{
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string PRICE { get; set; }
    public string TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
}
```

I get multiple Prices and Timestamps, so I want all the Prices in 1 List orderby Timestamp. I made this:

```
var singleNameWithOldestPrice =
    from p in PriceList
    where p.NAME.Contains(SelectedProduct, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    group p by p.NAME into grp
    select grp.OrderBy(a => a.TIMESTAMP);
```

Now I have a short list with all the prices and timestamps by 1 name.

How can I put every price in the chart orderby timestamp?
I hope my story has become a bit clear, if not... Please let me know?

PS: This is not going to work:

```
var singleNameWithOldestPrice =
    from p in PriceList
    where p.NAME.Contains(SelectedProduct, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    group p by p.NAME into grp
    select grp.OrderBy(a => a.TIMESTAMP).ToArray();

foreach (var p in singleNameWithOldestPrice)
{
     List<Microcharts.Entry> entries = new List<Microcharts.Entry>
     {
         new Entry(p)
         {
             Label = "p.NAME",
             ValueLabel = "p.PRICE",
             Color = SKColor.Parse("#2c3e50")
         }
     } 
}
```

Comment: add using Microcharts; to resolve your first problem

Comment: That doesn't work?

Comment: No matter what I do, it gives an error on Entry

Comment: have you installed the Microcharts libraries?

Comment: yes, the Nuget Package

Answer (score 1):

I found out that if you installed the Microcharts.Forms plugin, you also need to install the Microcharts plugin.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information to your answer so that other people can understand it more easily